# How to convert arguments to fit in vector matrix multiplication

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have three arguments which need to be vectors and a matrix to fit in an multiplication procedure. I tried all suggestions in the other questions but none worked.

```
LogLik=function(theta, r_t)
{
input=GARCH(theta, r_t)
error=input[,(1:4)]  #=e
Sigma=as.matrix(input[,(5:8)])
d=4 #combining 4 distributions
n= seq(from=1, to=((length(r_t$log_r1))*4)-3, by=4)
o= seq(from=4, to=(length(r_t$log_r1))*4, by=4)
for(i in 1:length(r_t$log_r1))
{
LLik=-(d/2)*log(2*pi)-(d/2)*log(det(Sigma[(n[i]:o[i]),]))-  (d/2)*t(error[i,])%*%solve(Sigma[(n[i]:o[i]),])%*%(error[i,])   #log-likelihoodfunction, multivariate
}
}
```

The problem is that the error and Sigma come from a data.frame(e,H_t) from a function before the one above. Now I want to have a scalar from

```
t(error[i,])%*%solve(Sigma[(n[i]:o[i]),])%*%(error[i,])
```

but nor is error  a vector argument niether Sigma is a matrix argument. I tried as.matrix and as.vector and so on. Is there a way without writing another function to change this?

Comment: How do you think anybody can help without having the input objects? Please, also indicate which package contains the `GARCH` function.

Comment: maybe like this, if your values come from a data.frame change error to error=as.matrix(input[,(1:4)]) then you don't need the t infornt of the first error moreover erase the % % last ones stay so you get a scalar.

Comment: @nicola Or a question!